# Calculate $\sup \{r \in \mathbb{R} : \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r^n n!}{n^n} = 0\}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, factorial

Determine $\alpha$, where
$$
\alpha \equiv \sup \left\{r \in \mathbb{R} : \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r^n n!}{n^n} = 0 \right\}
$$

---

### Some Observations

1. We clearly have $\alpha \geq 1$ since
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} = 0
   $$
   Moreover, Wolframalpha tells me
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n n!}{n^n} = \infty
   $$
   so $\alpha \leq 4$.
2. A basic estimate shows that
   $$
   0 \leq \frac{r^n n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{r^n}{2^n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
   $$
   which may be some kind of clue.
3. This is reminiscent of Stirling's approximation, which says
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^n n!}{n^{n + \frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{2\pi}
   $$
   But the $n + \frac{1}{2}$ in the exponent in the denominator prevents us from simply concluding that $\alpha = e$
4. Playing around in Wolframalpha, it seems like $\alpha = e$ is a good conjecture, but I haven't been able to confirm it. I also have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your guess is correct, and your problem can indeed be tackled by the Stirling's approximation:

  $$\frac{r^n n!}{n^n} \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\,\frac{r^n n^n e^{-n}}{n^n}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac{r}{e}\right)^n.$$

  Focusing on $r>0$, this limit converges if $r<e$ and diverges if $r\geq e$.
- In fact, we may borrow the idea from the Ratio Test and come up with a simpler argument. If $a_n$ denotes the expression inside of the limit, then

  $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{r}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}.$$

  Now by noting that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \uparrow e$ as $n\to\infty$,

  $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq \frac{r}{e} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{r}{e}. $$

  This can be used to prove that $a_n \to 0$ if $0 < r < e$ and $a_n \not\to 0$ if $r \geq e$.

Comment: Ah! So obvious now that I see it written out. Thanks. Nevertheless, I'm glad I asked. I hadn't thought to use the idea of the Ratio Test like this. Definitely something I'm adding to my toolkit.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, Glad it helped!